# How to calculate numbers (total) based on the checked checkboxes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a a few checkboxes on my page and each checkbox has a `data-price` attribute.

The `data-price` represents a price of an item.

I'm trying to calculate a `total value` based on the checked boxes that is checked and also make sure the deduct the value of the UN-CHECKED checkboxes from the total value.

So far I have done this:

https://jsfiddle.net/523q4n72/1/

The issue that I have is that when I add up the price, it works fine but when I uncheck a checkbox, the total value jumps to minus and it does some strange calculations.

To test it, just check the checkboxes and uncheck one or two of them to see the issue.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".checks", function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
    var tots = $('#tots').html();
    var setPrice = Number(price) + Number(tots);
    var ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
    $('#tots').text(ffp);
  } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
    var tots = $('#tots').html();
    var setPrice = Number(price) - Number(tots);
    var ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
    $('#tots').text(ffp);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>£<span id="tots">0.00</span></h4>
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
```

Answer (score 4):

DRY - Don't repeat yourself.

In this case Loop each checked checkbox.

I have extracted the function so we can call it when changed AND when loading in case a checkbox was already checked

```js
function calc() {
  var tots = 0;
  $(".checks:checked").each(function() {
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
    tots += parseFloat(price);
  });
  $('#tots').text(tots.toFixed(2));
}
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".checks", calc);
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>£<span id="tots">0.00</span></h4>
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" checked name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
```

Alternative way of calling and initialising

```
$(".checks").on("change", calc).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
var setPrice = Number(price) - Number(tots);
```

to

```
var setPrice = Number(tots) - Number(price);
```

and it should work fine. The issue is occurring as you are trying to subtract the total price from the checked element price.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/523q4n72/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A better idea is to recalculate the total sum each time from the currently checked elements (*instead of adding or subtracting based on the current element*)

And it is better to target the `change` event instead of the `click`.

```
$(document).on("change", ".checks", function() {
    var checked = $('.checks:checked'),
        sum = checked.get().reduce(function(prev, item) {
            return prev + parseFloat(item.getAttribute('data-price'));
        }, 0);

    $('#tots').text( sum.toFixed(2) );
});
```

Updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/523q4n72/3/

Comment: I would say this is a bit over the head of OP. I agree in principle - see my answer for a more understandable version I posted at the same time as you

Comment: @mplungjan fair point. Might work as an incentive to learn more, though, for a passing reader.

Answer (score 0):

You were subtracting the total from the number clicked. Line 19 should read

```
var setPrice = Number(tots) - Number(price);
```

rather than

```
var setPrice = Number(price) - Number(tots);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You must change `Number(price) - Number(tots)` to `Number(tots) - Number(price)` to have the right equation.

You redeclare everything every time, why not declare outside of the conditions ?

```
var price = 0;
var tots = "";
var setPrice = 0;
var ffp = 0;

$( document ).on( "click", ".checks", function() {
 if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){        
 price = $(this).attr("data-price");    
 tots = $('#tots').html();
 setPrice = Number(price) + Number(tots); 
 ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
 $('#tots').text(ffp);
} else if ($(this).prop('checked')==false){ 
 price = $(this).attr("data-price");
 tots = $('#tots').html();
 setPrice = Number(tots) - Number(price);
 ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
 $('#tots').text(ffp);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/523q4n72/5/

```js
var total = 0;
$(document).on("click", ".checks", function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    total += Number($(this).data("price"));
  } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
    total -= Number($(this).data("price"));   
  }
  $('#tots').text(Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>£<span id="tots">0.00</span></h4>
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why negative? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would just approach it a different way then you have. When `.checks` is clicked, [iterate over each checkbox and add the values of those checked (updated fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/523q4n72/6/). It seems much easier to read, imo.

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".checks", function() {

  //reset totals on each click
  var total = 0;

  //Add checked totals
  $('.checks').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) total += $(this).data('price');
  });

  //Update new total
  $('#tots').html(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at the item that is (un)checked, loop the ones that are checked using the `:checked` selector.

It simplifies your code:

```js
$('.checks').on('change', function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.checks:checked').each(function() {
    total += $(this).data('price');
  });
  $('#tots').text( total.toFixed(2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>£<span id="tots">0.00</span></h4>

<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
```

Comment: Beat you by 7 seconds!

Comment: ... yeah, but mine is better :). Why loop all items when you can loop only the checked ones :) @smilebomb

Answer (score 0):

```js
var setPrice = 0;

$( document ).on( "click", ".checks", function() {

 if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
       
var price = $(this).attr("data-price");

var tots = $('#tots').html();

var setPrice = Number(price) + Number(tots);
  
var ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
 
$('#tots').text(ffp);
    
    
}else if ($(this).prop('checked')==false){ 
      
   
var price = $(this).attr("data-price");

var tots = $('#tots').html();
 
var setPrice = Number(tots) - Number(price);
  
  
    var ffp = Math.round(setPrice * 100) / 100;
 
 $('#tots').text(ffp);
   
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>£<span id="tots">0.00</span></h4>

<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94

<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94

<input type="checkbox" name="something" class="checks" data-price="17.94">17.94
```

Comment: What did you do? Please accompany your answers with explanation and click TIDY before saving

Comment: Well I just declare setPrice out the $(document).ready... like a global variable that store the total, That sum the checked values and substract the unchecked values. Also , in the else statement I updated the setPrice operation. ORIGINAL: setPrice = Number(price) - Number(tots) UPDATED: var setPrice = Number(tots) - Number(price);

Comment: Update your answer instead of commenting

Comment: Thanks... @mplungjan